# Sample admob testunitid for testing

Tags: android, admob

I'm curious. Is there a test unit ad id for admob to be used for testing purpose without having to register with admob first and getting one from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no test unit ad id. Providing that will lead to abuse and defeat the purpose of using a test device id to test ads.